# What is this iPad app?

Tags: ios, ipad, applications

Saw an app during a Apple video, i was wondering what it was called.
[image: Unknown app]

Comment: [GarageBand](https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/garageband/id408709785?mt=8) maybe?

Comment: I already have [link](https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/garageband/id408709785)[GarageBand] and this screen is nowhere to be found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Rockmate](https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/rockmate/id417415477?mt=8&affId=1410283&ign-mpt=uo%3D4)

From the description (Rockmate alone was too short to be an answer ...)

> Rockmate have been featured on Apple iPad TV ads. Rockmate turns your
>   iPad into a complete music studio that is easy and super fun to use.